# Remove an item of an inner array inside an array - react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've an json data that has an array. Each element of an array has array named items. I want to remove the inner array element if the string doesnot match the itemName. I tried using filter method but its not working as expected. It only returns the matching inner array elements but all the outer array elements are removed too. 
P.S see the code, json data, the output I get and the expected output. Thanks in advance

Code:

```
const update2 =
 state.menuResponse.map(
       item => {
        return item.items.filter(item => (item.itemName).includes("C"))
})

console.log("menuSearcheddd", update2)
```

Json data

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "menuHeader": "Starters",
      "items": [
        {
          "itemId": "1",
          "itemName": "burger",
        },
        {
          "itemId": "ITD1ZYTH",
          "itemName": "Cheese balls",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "menuHeader": "string",
      "items": [
        {
          "itemId": "1",
          "itemName": "burger",
        },
        {
          "itemId": "2",
          "itemName": "burger-non veg",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "itemId": "ITD1ZYTH",
          "itemName": "Cheese balls",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "items": []
    }
  ]
}
```

What should be?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "menuHeader": "Starters",
      "items": [
        {
          "itemId": "ITD1ZYTH",
          "itemName": "Cheese balls",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "menuHeader": "string",
      "items": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer elements are removed not because of the `filter` method, but because of the `map` method. See, in your `map` method you are disregarding every other property because you only return what you process on the `items` array.

So, code should look more like this:

```
const update2 = state.menuResponse.map(item => ({ ...item, items: item.items.filter(subItem => subItem.itemName.includes('C')) }));
```

So that from your `map` method you are returning everything that was inside you object before processing it and only modifying the `items` property by filtering the array like you have already done it.

Haven't managed to test it, but should work, in theory...

Comment: Perfect answer for nested array inside array delete.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = this.state.materialList.filter(item => {
            //Filter Inner Array 
            var innerData = item.data.filter(dataItem => {
                return dataItem.qty > 0
            })
            // Assign value
            item.data = innerData;
            return item.Id > 0
        })
 console.log('Filtered List ',list);
```